# Twitter says I have to confirm my account

Tags: twitter

Here's the thing: it sent me a confirmation e-mail, and I clicked "confirm." It immediately opened my account in a new window - but with the yellow banner reading "Confirm your e-mail address to access all of twitter's features..." still across the top of the page.

I clicked resend, got another e-mail, clicked "confirm," which opened up my account in a new window, and the yellow banner was still there. I did this again. And again. So I went through every help topic, then googled and tried the help advice give to another person with a similar question here (which is how I found this site.) That sent me to a twitter page where I had to re-do my password, and after, it sent me to my twitter page... which still had the banner. I entered my e-mail into my details, and it said it was sending a confirmation of my "new" e-mail address, but it didn't. So I clicked "resend confirmation" again, got another e-mail, clicked "confirm" again, my twitter opened up again, and the BANNER WAS STILL THERE. Will it never go away?

Comment: Just give a try. Logout from your twitter account, clear browser and then login direct your twitter account (not from link.)

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/84611/87130