# Twitter 'confirm email' message won't go away after trying everything I could find online to try

Tags: twitter

Two other people on this forum have asked this question and I have tried the advice given in both responses, but it still won't work for me. I've searched everywhere else online and cannot find any other information regarding this issue.

I am a new twitter user. After creating my account, a yellow message appears asking me to confirm my email address. I go to my email and hit the "confirm" button. Then my twitter opens in a new window and the message is still there. I've signed in and signed out, resent, tried again. Still there. I've cleared my browser history, tried different browsers, waited a few days, resent and hit the confirm email button after trying each of these things and still the message is there.

I sent a message to Twitter regarding the issue but it says that they don't respond to individual emails. I'm not sure what else to do or what I am doing wrong. Would greatly appreciate anyone's help on this.

Comment: You can give a try by changing email address temporarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Help Center](https://support.twitter.com/articles/82050):

**I'm having trouble confirming my email address**

> [Nothing is working. Help!](https://support.twitter.com/articles/82050#nothing-works)
>
> If you’ve tried resending the email and you are still having trouble, here are some troubleshooting tips:
>
> 1. Are we sending it to the wrong email address? Double check your [Account settings](https://twitter.com/settings/account) to make sure your email is entered accurately. See any typos? Do we have an old email on file? Make any necessary corrections and click save; we’ll send another email if you’ve updated the address.
> 2. Try changing the email address to an email address with a large domain (Gmail, Yahoo, etc.). We tend to have more success delivering emails to those types of domains.
> 3. Still need help? Contact us [here](https://support.twitter.com/forms/signin).

Comment: Thanks for replying. Unfortunately, the issue isn't with receiving the email. I do receive the emails. The problem is when I click on the "Confirm Email" button within the email, it opens my Twitter account but the yellow message telling me that I need to confirm my email address is still there, covering the header. When I hit resend, I receive the email, try again, and still the message won't go away. Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: In my answer , last line have a link to contact Twitter. You can contact them. Otherwise you can wait for sometime. Or you can just change your email and try to verify new email address.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again for responding! It now works. I'm posting what happened in case anyone else runs into this.

I changed my email address linked with Twitter to a new account per [serenesat](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/87130/serenesat)'s [suggestion](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/84611/87130). I received the confirmation email in the new account, hit confirm, and the yellow box was still present. I tried to resend the confirmation and this time did not receive it. So I checked in my old email address box in case and the latest confirm email had been sent there instead. I hit confirm and this time my account was confirmed (to my old address rather than the new one) and the yellow box is finally gone!

Thanks again for all the help. I really appreciate it.